# ajax request do not response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

here is my code what i done

```
function price() {

    var quantity = document.getElementById("quan").value;
    var select = document.getElementById("p_id");
    var product_id = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;



    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            //alert("working");
            document.getElementById("price_ajax").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_product.php?p_id=" + product_id + "&quantity=" + quantity);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

and here is my php code which execute ajax request:

```
$p_id = intval($_GET['p_id']);
$quantity = intval($_GET['quantity']);

$connection=new Database();



$sth=$connection->DBH->prepare("SELECT `unit_price` FROM `product_lookup` WHERE `id`=?");

$sth->bindParam(1,$p_id);
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$rs=$sth->execute();
$row =$sth->fetch();


$product_price= intval($row->unit_price);

$total_price=$product_price*$quantity;

?>

<input value="<?php echo $p_id?>">
```

and here is my html :

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="price[]" id="price_ajax" >
```

this is where i call javascript function:

```
<input class="form-control" type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quan" oninput="price()" required>
```

this is the situation my ajax request do not  response anything

Comment: I think you forgot to include your HTML

Comment: Now you forgot to include where you actually CALL price()

Comment: @blue Boy i include  html

Comment: Now press F12 and look in the console

Comment: @ mplungjan i added oninput

Comment: Manually visit your PHP script via the browser and set the GET parameters manually see if it's 500ing

Comment: A point to mention. When setting `input` element's value, you should use its `value` attribute. So change `document.getElementById("price_ajax").innerHTML` to `document.getElementById("price_ajax").value`.

Comment: @Behrad Khodayar after adding in browser console shows The specified value "\r\n\u003Cinput value=\"275\"\u003E" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange @ purchaseDetails.php:233
purchaseDetails.php:233 The specified value "\r\n\u003Cinput value=\"3300\"\u003E" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+\.\d+|\.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Comment: So it seems this is the problem. just cast (this.responseText) to number(may be float) and then I think you are done. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Check this: `document.getElementById("price_ajax").innerHTML = parseFloat(this.responseText);`